# How to enable gboard gif insertion/upload on webpages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, copy-paste, gif, gboard

Google's Android keyboard [GBoard allows insertion of gifs](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/12/gboard-expands-keyboard-gif-support-beyond-android-7-1/) in some apps, e.g. Hangouts. I would like to enable this functionality on a website as well.

How do I communicate to Google Chrome, and then to the GBoard, that this gif upload is enabled on my `<textarea>` and how do I handle it?